# Scheduling a series of tasks with irregular intervals in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, scheduled-tasks

Say I have a file that lists tasks to perform and an interval to perform them after like:

```
Task_A
2 seconds
Task_B
10 seconds
Task_C
1 minute
Task_A
...
```

And so when this list is read in, and then allowed to execute, it does Task_A, waits 2 seconds, performs Task_B, waits 10 seconds, and so on.

How should I do this?  I have looked a little into System.threading.timer, but that seems to be a for a set interval doing a repeated task, but in this case I am reading in a file that lists what to do and how long before you do it like above (a different syntax, but this one made it easier to explain).

This function is in a backgroundworker, so I could do a Thread.Sleep(Timespan) and not have any issue for my GUI, but that feels like hammering a nail with an anvil.  I could also have as part of the System.threading.timer's OnTimedEvent have a part that alters its own Interval, but I'm not sure if that is a good practice, or if it would even work.

What is best way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with using BackgroundWorker/Thread.Sleep? Also, does Task_B start 2 secs after previous task completes or 2 secs after it starts?

Comment: +1 to @muratgu; I'd also suggest that you can use a Timer by resetting the interval each time you start the timer.

Comment: For the Thread.Sleep comment, one reason was that I wasn't positive if it was a busy-wait or not.  Secondly, in this actual program, Task_A may not actually start for a while, hours away even, and I planned to submit to some scheduler:  run Task_A at 12:00:00, Task_B at 12:00:02, etc.  These DateTimes would be determined from the delays listed in the scheduling file.

Comment: For the start or end question, it doesn't really matter very much in this case, but lets say that task B starts 2 seconds after Task_A starts.  The task itself is only takes a few milliseconds and the delays will usually be high (like minutes or hours), but may be as low as 250 ms.  In the case of the 250 ms ones, their timing is not critical, and so it running at 275 ms, or even 500 ms is not a deal-breaker.

Answer (score 0):

System.Timers.Timer can help.

First, basic class for task, you would probably have it by your database or some other way.

```
public class Task
{
    public Task()
    { 

    }

    public Task(String tName, Int32 iInterval, Int16 iPriority)
    {
        this.taskName = tName;
        this.nextInterval = iInterval;
        this.priority = iPriority;
    }

    private String taskName = String.Empty;

    public String TaskName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.taskName;
        }
        set
        {
            this.taskName = value;
        }
    }

    private Int32 nextInterval = 1;

    public Int32 NextInterval
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nextInterval;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nextInterval = value;
        }
    }

    private Int16 priority = 1;

    public Int16 Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return this.priority;
        }
        set
        {
            this.priority = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then the how to execute part.

```
public class ExecuteTasks
{
    private System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    private Int32 TaskIndex = 0;
    private Int32 TaskCount = 3;

    protected void StartExecution()
    {
        myTimer.Interval = 1;
        myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
        myTimer.Start();
    }

    void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTimer.Stop();

        if (TaskIndex < TaskCount)
        {             
            Task aTask = GetTasks()[TaskIndex++];
            StartTask(aTask.TaskName);
            SetNextTaskTimer(aTask.NextInterval);
        }
    }

    void SetNextTaskTimer(Int32 Seconds)
    {   
        myTimer.Interval = (Seconds * 1000) - DateTime.Now.Millisecond - 1;//Interval is set in miliseconds
        myTimer.Start();
    }

    void StartTask(String TaskName)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo objStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        objStartInfo.FileName = TaskName;

        Process objProcess = new Process();
        objProcess.StartInfo = objStartInfo;
        objProcess.Start();
    }

    //You will be reading your tasks from your database or a file
    List<Task> GetTasks()
    {
        List<Task> lstTasks = new List<Task>();

        lstTasks.Add(new Task("Task A", 2, 1));
        lstTasks.Add(new Task("Task B", 10, 2));
        lstTasks.Add(new Task("Task C", 60, 3));

        return lstTasks.OrderBy(le => le.Priority).ToList();
    }
}
```

I have started some processes, when the given time is elapsed. (You will need to provide right path for the process to start. i.e something like

```
ProcessStartInfo objStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
objStartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe";
```

instead of just task name.

And finally to trigger the execution part.

```
ExecuteTasks iExecute = new ExecuteTasks();
iExecute.StartExecution();
```

For multithreading you can use lock mechanism, monitor classes etc, whichever suits your needs. i.e.

```
lock(obj)//lock on an object
{
    ExecuteTasks iExecute = new ExecuteTasks();
    iExecute.StartExecution();
}
```